# intellij no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Flux<R> conforms to Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> issue

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, project-reactor

I'm trying to convert a `Mono<Part>` to a `Mono<InputStream>`, using java with reactor and spring.

I have a code which compiles and works properly, but it generates an Intellij error.

The code:

```
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils;
import org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.Part;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import java.io.InputStream;

public Mono<InputStream> loadFile(Mono<Part> fileMono) {
  return DataBufferUtils.join(fileMono.flatMapMany(Part::content))
                        .map(DataBuffer::asInputStream);
}
```

The error:

```
Required type: Publisher

Provided: Flux <org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer>

no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Flux<R> conforms to Publisher<? extends DataBuffer>
```

As `Flux<T> implements CorePublisher<T>` and `CorePublisher<T> extends Publisher<T>`, I don't understand the error.
Moreover some of my co-workers have the error when others don't.
This is pretty weird.

I've tried to delete and reimport the library dependencies through gradle, and to do all 7 intellij steps to debug a project, including clearing cache and reindexing the app.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently there are errors with the Kotlin Plugin in Intellij.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-16925

Suggested solutions are:

- Desactivating Kotlin plugin
- Rollback to an older Kotlin plugin version

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this issue is fixed in current beta version of kotlin plugin: 232-1.9.20-RC-release-459-IJ9559.62

Steps to fix error:

1. Install beta kotlin plugin in Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Kotlin
2. Delete spring core jar. Can be done in project window: External Libraries -> Scripts build.gradle.kts -> spring-core-*.*.*.jar
3. Reload Gradle project

Comment: Nice! Good to know. I'm now waiting for the official release